# Returning a reference to an object in java, StringBuilder reverse()

Tags: java, oop, reference

So for example in the oracle docs for the StringBuilder reverse() function the doc's say "a reference to this object" is returned. So if A is an object of type StringBuilder and I call A.reverse() then a reference to the reverse of A is returned but where is it returned to? If a reference is being returned dont I need to do:

```
StringBuilder A = new StringBuilder("HELLLO");
StringBuilder B = new StringBuilder();
B = A.reverse();
```

How come I can just do:

```
A.reverse();
```

why is A's reference automatically changed to the reference returned by the reverse function?

Also if I did:

```
A = A.reverse();
```

does this also store the reverse value in A?

Comment: `A.reverse();` - `A` is not declared anywhere...

Comment: Are you asking what it means to return a reference value?

Comment: `A` reference is not changed, `A` is reversed. It still points to itself, just the value has changed.

Comment: `A = A.reverse();` has exactly the same effect as `A.reverse();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StringBuilder is mutable. If you start with `StringBuilder a` then `a.reverse()` returns a reference to `a`.

Comment: but how come that reference is assigned to a?

Comment: You've created it, when you said `StringBuilder a = new StringBulder();` somewhere. If you later go `StringBuilder b = a.reverse();` Now both `a` and `b` refer to the same object.

Comment: It's maybe the word `this` that's confusing you. Reverse() method actually goes `return this;` when it's done. That's what they mean in the doc that it's returning a reference to this object.

Comment: That makes sense how did you know that they mean return this?

Comment: I use that in my own method comments. Referring to the instance as this in the comments is common.

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` returns this to allow method chaining, it actually updates in place. Consider,

```
System.out.println(a.reverse().toString().toLowerCase());
```

If `reverse()` was `void` then you could not chain the calls.